# Symfony 6 decorating an interface and specify the default implementation using annotations?

Tags: symfony

The `FilterMetadataFactory` class is (for now) **the only implementation** of `FilterMetadataFactoryInterface`.

```php
class FilterMetadataFactory implements FilterMetadataFactoryInterface
{
}
```

In **production only**, the default implementation should be decorated by the `CachedFilterMetadataFactory`:

```php
#[When('prod')]
#[AsDecorator(decorates: FilterMetadataFactoryInterface::class, priority: -10)]
class CachedFilterMetadataFactory implements FilterMetadataFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly CacheInterface $cache,
        #[MapDecorated]
        private readonly FilterMetadataFactoryInterface $decorated,
   ) {
   }
}
```

**This is not working**: of course Symfony complains about non-existent service `FilterMetadataFactoryInterface` because I didn't define an alias.

How can I define the alias using annotations, when multiple classes implements the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to myself digging into the source code: it's added in 6.3: [`AsAlias`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Attribute/AsAlias.php).

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for the autowiring to alias the decorator with the highest priority in this case?